# List Server which are not part of this deployment in server pool

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, system-administration, servermanager, remote-development

Is there a way to get the list of servers available to add to the server pool?

I need to get the server list via PowerShell which is listed as Server Manager (Refer to attached Screenshot)[image]

Comment: Where is your code to help you with?